# Tooltips are not captured by leaflet-image

Tags: leaflet, html, html5

I am trying to capture my map with `leaflet-image`, but the tooltips are not captured. I enabled `preferCanvas` in the `mapOptions` and everything except from the tooltips is captured. Each one of my markers has tooltips. The tooltips seem to be drawn in HTML. I have even tried to do something like this:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText(feature.properties.test_number,10,50);
return canvas;
```

The numbers are now in canvas. But the wrapper still is in HTML - I believe by default from Leaflet. I have no problem modifying my tooltips (they're just numbers) to be in canvas or modify the way I am doing things in general to make the capture possible.

Why are tooltips not being captured in screenshot?

My goal is the  ability for `leaflet-image` to be able to capture the tooltips that are bound to the markers.

[image: Map Actual]
[image: Leaflet-Image Output]

Map Doesn't render (due to Bing Maps issue -- different Issue)

Comment: Can you add one of your screenshots and maybe a [mockup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockup#Software_engineering) of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Stefan, no problem. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`L.tooltip`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#tooltip) is a built-in feature of Leaflet since version 1.0.0 based on the plugin [`Leaflet.label`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label). [`leaflet-image`](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image) in turn says in their README:

> #### Plugins that will not work with leaflet-image
>
> - Leaflet.label: will not work because it uses HTML to display labels.

[This answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6789627/9778755) regarding the conversion of a HTML element to a `<canvas>` element might help you:

> There is a library that try to do what you say.
>
> See this examples and get the code
>
> http://hertzen.com/experiments/jsfeedback/
>
> http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/
>
> Reads the DOM, from the html and render it to a canvas, fail on some,
>   but in general works.

Comment: Stefan, as you can see I have already tried things of this nature. I understand that lelaflet-image won't do that. I wrote in my post that I understand that it renders in HTML and that's why. My request is for help (maybe code example) to try to figure out a way to have labels that render in canvas.

Comment: I will however mark this answer acceptable as you lead me to an article with html2canvas + leaflet and will probably use this method to achieve the goal. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks! I invite you to improve my answer with the link to that article.

Comment: It's worth noting that `L.Tooltip` is built-in into Leaflet since version 1.0.0 (it was a plugin for 0.7.x, based on the leaflet.label plugin). Your answer still stands, though, as the built-in `L.Tooltip` (and `L.Popup` and `L.DivIcon`) use HTML elements that `leaflet-image` cannot flatten into a `<canvas>`.

Comment: @IvanSanchez I added the information about L.Tooltip being built in to the answer. Thanks!